# How to read one line from `tail -f` through a pipeline, and then terminate?

Tags: bash, unix

I would like to follow changes to a file via `tail -f` and then print out the first line that matches a `grep` command before terminating. What's the simplest way to do this? So far I've been experimenting with things like:

```
tail -f foo.log | grep 'bar' | head -1
```

However, the pipeline just hangs, presumably due to buffering. I also tried

```
tail -f foo.log | grep --line-buffered 'bar' | head -1
```

This prints out the line, but the process does not terminate unless I hit ^C, presumably because a second line of input is needed to terminate `head -1`. What's the best way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
tail -f foo.log | grep -m 1 bar
```

if the file foo.log is writen rarily to, you can do:

```
grep -m 1 bar <( tail -f foo.log )
```

It should be noted that the tail -f will stay in background until it will get another line to output. If this takes long time it might be problematic. solution in such case is:

```
grep -m 1 bar <( exec tail -f foo.log ); kill $! 2> /dev/null
```

kill will kill leftover tail -f process, and we hide errors, because it's possible that the tail will be gone by the time kill will be invoked.

Comment: Doesn't work for me.

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work for me". Is there any error message? Anything happens? Does your grep support -m option?

Comment: Bah sorry I was too late on the edit. It doesn't terminate for me.

Comment: This means that either the grepped string is not there, or the pipe to grep is buffered. test with this: `perl -e '$|++; my $i = "a"; while (1) { print $i, "\n"; $i++; select undef, undef, undef, 0.1}'  | grep -m 1 aa` - every 0.1 second it prints next string, first "a", then "b", ... "z", "aa", "ab" ... - grep finishes after "aa", so it should be ~ 2.7 second after start. and it works. the problem might be if you have something else between tail -f .. and | grep - like another grep, sed or something like this.

Comment: Oh... I've been testing on auth.log, grepping for 'a'. If there's an initial match it seems its not terminating until the file gets a little more appended to..

Comment: Well, yes. Grep finishes instantly, but tail will finish when it encounters error. Error will happen when it will try to write to closed pipe - i.e. tail will finish on next write.

Comment: @PriceChild: ok. the problem with waiting for SIGPIPE is solved in the new solution.

Comment: That works! Will reverse my vote.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The second solution is what I needed, since only one line from `tail -f` would match.

Comment: Is the reason why the first line does not terminate immediately that `tail` doesn't get a SIGPIPE until it tries to write to the pipe?

Answer (score 2):

The <() construct works in bash only. My solution is:

```
sleep $timeout &
pid=$!
tail -n +0 --pid=$pid -F "$file" | ( grep -q -m 1 "$regexp" && kill -PIPE $pid )
wait $pid
```

Besides it's working in a POSIX shell, one other advantage is that the waiting period can be limited with a timeout value. Note that the result code of this scriptlet is reversed: 0 means the timeout was reached.

Comment: Having read all the answers I think this answer needs to be highlighted a bit. Although the -m is has its uses with grep it's the --pid flag for tail that I use ten times more often. It is a very good tool for cases like these.

Answer (score 1):

`tail -f` waiting for `SIGPIPE`, which, as already pointed out by depesz, can only be triggered by another write of `tail -f` to a closed pipe after a successful `grep -m 1` match, can be avoided if the `tail -f` command gets backgrounded and its background pid being sent to the `grep` subshell, which in turn implements a `trap` on exit that kills `tail -f` explicitly.

```
#(tail -f foo.log & echo ${!} ) |
(tail -f foo.log & echo ${!} && wait ) | 
   (trap 'kill "$tailpid"; trap - EXIT' EXIT; tailpid="$(head -1)"; grep -m 1 bar)
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on answer https://superuser.com/a/275962/37154 , I realized that if the `tail` would start too late, some instance of the indicated string may have gone by already. The solution is to make tail list the whole file.

```
grep -m 1 bar <( exec tail -n +1 -f foo.log ); kill $!
```

Answer (score -1):

I think that applying [unbuffer](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/unbuffer1.html) like this,

```
tail -f foo.log | unbuffer -p grep 'bar' | head -1
```

would work. I'm not at a system where I can test it, though, and I can't justify why it would work while `grep --line-buffered` does not. However, I did try this alternative which does seem to work:

```
tail -f foo.log | sed -n '/bar/{p;q}'
```

When the match to `bar` is found, `p` prints it and `q` immediately quits.

Comment: Neither work for me. (They don't terminate)