# Stopping after first line of output

Tags: bash, script, head

I try to do the following in a Bash script: run a command (such as `tail -f log_file`), wait until a specific output arrives, then stop the command, and go on with the script.

I tried the following, but it didn't work:

```
tail -f log_file | grep some_text | head -n1
```

I got no output this way.

Now, I tried to diagnose the problem. When I simply run `tail -n1`, then type something into the terminal, it exits after the first line. However, if I run the following:

```
grep some_text | head -n1
```

In this case, I get no output until I press CTRL+D, and then it prints the first line of the input containing `some_text`.

My question is, why is this? If `head` outputs the first line immediately in the first case, why doesn't it do when it gets the input from a pipe? Shouldn't it output everything for the first *n* lines, then exit, sending a SIGPIPE signal to the other end of the pipe?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following this very well. Do you get output if you do `tail -f log_file | grep some_text`

Comment: I get output only at the end of the input stream. When I don't use grep, I get output immediately. Also, if I use grep, but no head, I get output immediately, too.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/275827/how-to-read-one-line-from-tail-f-through-a-pipeline-and-then-terminate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`grep` buffers your input. Try `grep --line-buffered`.

There's an additional problem, `head` will only terminate after it receives a second line which can be a problem if your logfile is low-frequency. See [How to read one line from `tail -f` through a pipeline, and then terminate?](https://superuser.com/questions/275827/how-to-read-one-line-from-tail-f-through-a-pipeline-and-then-terminate).

Answer (score 0):

When you run `tail -n1` with no input, it will exit after the first line of input from STDIN, that is how it should work. When you run `grep some_text | head -n1` you are again not supplying any input to `grep`, so it would seem that the behavior that I think you are describing is normal. When you press CTRL D, you are closing the STDIN pipe, and `head -n1` is outputting what `grep received from STDIN.